# Axis Aligned Bounding Box Skimage

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, scikit-image

How do I generate an axis-aligned bounding box for a numpy array with an arbitrary shape mask?

I know the equivalent in OpenCV is the `minAreaRect`. Is their something like that in skimage?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample code:
Sample image: [stars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpkUE.png)

1.read image:

```
from skimage.measure import find_contours
from skimage.io import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
orig_img = imread('resources/stars.jpg')
gray_img = rgb2gray(orig_img)
plt.imshow(gray_img,interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

2.Find countours:

```
contours = find_contours(gray_img, 0.8)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(gray_img, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
for n, contour in enumerate(contours):
    ax.plot(contours[n][:, 1], contours[n][:, 0], linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

output: [countors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIqB0.png)
3. Draw bounding box:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.draw import polygon_perimeter
bounding_boxes = []

for contour in contours:
    Xmin = np.min(contour[:,0])
    Xmax = np.max(contour[:,0])
    Ymin = np.min(contour[:,1])
    Ymax = np.max(contour[:,1])

bounding_boxes.append([Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax])
with_boxes  = np.copy(gray_img)
for box in bounding_boxes:
    #[Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax]
    r = [box[0],box[1],box[1],box[0], box[0]]
    c = [box[3],box[3],box[2],box[2], box[3]]
    rr, cc = polygon_perimeter(r, c, with_boxes.shape)
    with_boxes[rr, cc] = 1 #set color white
plt.imshow(with_boxes, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

output:
[bounding box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNyIm.png)

Comment: Surely your answer produces an image? Please consider adding the image to make the answer more useful to other folk. Thank you.

Comment: you do generate bounding boxes but they are not axis aligned. the opencv `minAreaRect` for details.